# How did scientists calculate the bounds of mass of Higgs boson without measurement

Tags: mass, field-theory, higgs

First of all, let us write out the lagrangian of the Higgs field

$\mathcal{L}=\partial_\mu\bar{\varphi}\partial^\mu\varphi-\lambda(\bar{\varphi}\varphi-\frac{v^2}{2})^2$

This yields $m^2=\lambda v^2$. The constant $v$ can be easily found from masses of W- and Z-bosons, since $m_W=\frac{gv}{2}$ and $m_Z=\frac{gv}{2\,cos\,\theta_W}$

The problem is to find $\lambda$, because it appears only in self-interaction of Higgs field.

So, my question is how did scientist approximated Higgs mass without experimental measurement?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The Higgs mass has been measured experimentally.

Comment: But before that there were theoretical bounds of its mass. In which energy scale we need to search for the Higgs boson.

Comment: when I google "estimate of higgs mass" a number of articles appear . examples  https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.3753  ,  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269301014496